# Images in Images.xcassets Not Showing up When Archiving App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, archive, xcasset

I am using Xcode 5.1.1 and images.xcassets to store a significant amount of my app's images (I realize now that by doing this, building and running my app now takes significantly longer). Anywho, everything works as expected. When I hook up by device and run it, all the images show up fine.

The problem is, when I archive my project to send to my beta testers, upon installing it through those means, the app does not show any of my images that are stored in images.xcassets, but other images stored normally do appear (The icons stored in images.xcassets do appear though).

What could be wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Having the same problem here. Does it work OK if you run directly on your device in release mode? Not through TestFlight?

Comment: i have the same issue.. do u got a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround that works well for me.
I faced the same issue and found out the problem was the deployment target version. When changing deployment target from iOS 6.0 to iOS 8.0, many images which were part of a image catalogue(image.xcasset) were not seen when creating an archive and sharing with the testers. It worked fine when running the development build on the same iphone.
On changing back the deployment target from iOS 8.0 to iOS 6.0 and creating an archive again those images were seen. So workaround is to change the deployment target back to 6.0. Not sure if there is a iOS bug for this though.